# Fail to set ulimit inside docker container

Tags: docker, ulimit

I have committed a ubuntu image with a new user call "user"
and then i create the container with the following command

```
 sudo docker run -u=user -ti test1 /bin/bash
```

I check that there are only two process running

```
user@1bc12c468f29:/$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1 ?        00:00:00 bash
   12 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

But after i set

```
ulimit -u 10
```

I cannot create any new process, even ls

```
user@1bc12c468f29:/$ ulimit -u 10
user@1bc12c468f29:/$ ls
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Should ulimit -u 10  allow 10 processes running simultaneously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set ulimit / file descriptor on docker container the image tag is phusion/baseimage-docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion)

Comment: Thanks for you comment.
In that post, he tries to rise the limit.
But in my situation, i try to lower the limit, and it should work, but the result is strange. You suggestion seems not help much

Comment: I guess there are hidden user process for each user. You can try `ulimit 20`, it shall work and also `ulimit -u` will report current number

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you are correct.
And i got more detail in this post [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/449363/understanding-ulimit-u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output of `ps` doesn't give list of all running processes. It only gives list of processes running in your TTY. To get list of all running processes you can run: `ps -ef`. To get total number: `ps -ef|wc -l`