# Docker service with ulimit

Tags: docker, service, ulimit

The approach used to set the ulimit on a container does not work for services.

For containers, it's as simple as passing a `ulimit` parameter on the `docker run` command.

For *services*, is is possible on the command line? `Ulimit` is not recognized as a flag.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion) for a relevant question on containers (note: does *not* apply to services).

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit` option is not available for docker services. You can instead create a configuration file (mylimits.conf) with the necessary configuration and add (or update) it to your service.

```
# docker config create mylimits.conf

# docker service create \
    --name nginx \
    --config source=mylimits.conf,target=/etc/security/limits.d/mylimits.conf \
    nginx:latest \
    sh -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```