# Node.js error: "Cannot assign to read only property '_connections'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm having this problem on node 4.2.4 when the number of server requests are getting to a certain level. The error is `Cannot assign to read only property '_connections'` and points to [this line of code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/13151aae1a5e6e22052efd1816cc35bc1aae377c/lib/net.js#L1428).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Once the maximum number of connections is reached, everything stops being writable and becomes read only.

Increase the number of max connections.

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();
server.maxConnections = 100 //or whatever number you want
```

Comment: But this doesn't seem to be on by default. Right? In node's documentation says to set it only if you need to limit the number of connections.

Comment: which library exactly are you using? If it's a wrapper around net.js it's possible a default number is already set?

Comment: I thought about that. I'm using express. I tried searching trough the codebase (node_modules included) for "maxConnections" and nothing shows up

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu inside Docker

Comment: Docker has a default ulimit which could be causing this problem. Try the last answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion