# Running Lightttpd in Docker: ulimits not honored

Tags: sockets, docker, lighttpd, ulimit

I am trying to run lighttpd (1.4.35) inside of a Docker container to serve a high-volume static website (no PHP, et al). After a minute of running, the error log fills with :

> (server.c.1444) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached

I've upped the limits for `root` in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (and rebooted):

```
root            soft    nofile          4096
root            hard    nofile          32768
```

And in my `docker-compose.yml` (equivalent to `--ulimit` on the command line):

```
ulimits:
  nofile:
    soft: 4096
    hard: 32768
```

And in my `lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.max-fds = 8192
server.max-connections = 4096
```

But when I run `lsof -n | grep -c lighttpd` I get no higher than 128. If I enter the container and run `ulimit -n` I get 4096, as expected. Running `ulimit -a` returns:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128490
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What else am I missing? How do I get lighttpd to accept more than 128 connections?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set ulimit / file descriptor on docker container the image tag is phusion/baseimage-docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion)

Comment: As I said in my original post, I have set the limits in Docker, albeit using the compose file (as I'm using docker-compose) and not the command line. I edited the post to make this point explicitly.

Comment: What is the version of `lighttpd` you are using?

Comment: `lighttpd-1.4.35`. Updated the post.