# Unable to start cassandra on docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am unable to start cassandra on docker container, seems to be a permissions issue. Please suggest an alternate.

**Refer Logs:**

```html
*Created container adf1efd4de6eb8030a1963089715a80a0ec8e5f2cc1f1f50d867cab7d33c4920, for #26
19:15:08 Starting container with:
19:15:08 CMD:'',
19:15:08 Entrypoint:
19:15:08 '/bin/sh','/tmp/executor.sh',
19:15:08 Started container adf1efd4de6eb8030a1963089715a80a0ec8e5f2cc1f1f50d867cab7d33c4920
19:15:08 Starting script executor 19:15:08 Creating group... 19:15:09 Creating user...
19:15:09 * Cassandra is not running
19:15:09 /etc/init.d/cassandra: 71: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
19:15:09 /etc/init.d/cassandra: 72: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
19:15:09 install: cannot change owner and permissions of '/var/run/cassandra': No such file or directory
19:15:10 start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 106 (Operation not permitted) 19:15:20 * Cassandra is not running
19:15:20 Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
19:15:20 Removing container adf1efd4de6eb8030a1963089715a80a0ec8e5f2cc1f1f50d867cab7d33c4920*
```

**Docker File:**

```html
FROM hub.docker.prod.walmart.com/library/ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV http_proxy http://gec-proxy-svr.homeoffice.wal-mart.com:8080
ENV https_proxy http://gec-proxy-svr.homeoffice.wal-mart.com:8080
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common debconf-utils
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
RUN echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list

RUN gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys F758CE318D77295D \
&& gpg --export --armor F758CE318D77295D | apt-key add -
RUN gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 2B5C1B00 \
&& gpg --export --armor 2B5C1B00 | apt-key add -
RUN gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0353B12C \
&& gpg --export --armor 0353B12C | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -y
EXPOSE 9042
RUN apt-get install --quiet --yes --force-yes cassandra
#RUN sleep 10s
#RUN service cassandra start
#RUN sleep 10s
#RUNservice cassandra status
```

Comment: Can you share the text of the Dockerfile?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson: Added the dockerfile text.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion

Answer (score 0):

I've compared your Dockerfile to the Docker Hub one here:
https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/master/3.11/Dockerfile

(Different versions as needed are available higher in the page hierarchy.)

You have most of the elements in your Dockerfile, but there are some commands to create directories in the official Dockerfile.

You could use this official one as an alternate.