# Docker service won't run inside Container - ERROR : ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

I'm running a cluster on AWS EKS. Container(StatefulSet POD) that currently running has Docker installation inside of it.

I ran this image as Kubernetes StatefulSet in my cluster. Here is my yaml file,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  labels:
    run: jenkins
spec:
  serviceName: jenkins
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: jenkins
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: 99*****.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<my_jenkins_image>:0.0.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: jenkins-port
```

Inside this POD, I can not run any docker command which gives a ERROR:

> /etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

In my research, I went through some artcile which did not fix my issue.
I have listed down solution that i tried but not fixed in my case

**First solution: (I ran inside the container)**
[aricle link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion)

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo bash -c "echo \"limit nofile 262144 262144\" >> /etc/init/docker.conf"
$ sudo service docker start
```

**Second solution: (I ran inside the container)**

```
ulimit -n 65536 in /etc/init.d/docker
```

**Third solution: ** [article link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450799/getting-operation-not-permitted-error-when-setting-ulimit-for-memlock-in-a-doc)
This seems a far better answer, which i could not add into my configuration file.
it says, run pod with as privilaged. But there is no way to add that option in ***Kubernetes StatefulSet*** .
So I tried by adding a SecurityContext **(securityContext:fsGroup: 1000)** like this inside configuration file,

```
spec:
  serviceName: jenkins
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: jenkins
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
```

still it does not work.

**Note :same image worked on Docker swarm**

Anyhelp would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with Elastic Search and adding `initContainer` worked. In this case it could be the solution:

```
spec:
  .
  .
  .
  initContainers:  
  - name: increase-fd-ulimit
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

If it doesn't work, there is a [second](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3595#issuecomment-487919341) way to solve this problem which includes creating a new Dockerfile or changing existing:

```
FROM 99*****.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<my_jenkins_image>:0.0.3
RUN ulimit -n 65536
USER 1000
```

and change securityContext to:

```
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
    capabilities:
      add: ["IPC_LOCK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the POD container need runtime privilege and Linux capabilities
For example, in the docker outside container , You need to give privilege to this container

`docker run --privileged`

then , this docker could execute `service docker start`, to use docker command inside container

there is the setting for kubernetes API's Controller and Pod :

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name:  pause
      image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

or creating `PodSecurityPolicy`.