# Docker Build doesn't work inside AWS EKS's worker nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In my local machine, I can build the image from the Dockerfile of my Nodejs Project. But I cloned that project inside **AWS EKS's worker node** and tried to build the image but it did not work. (**Note**: `*the reason that I ran the docker build on a worker node, previous I tried to build an image inside Jenkins and it gives the same result as what I got the error inside worker nodes*`).

Error:

```
docker build -t crmproxy .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.451MB

Step 1/9 : FROM node:8
 ---> c83f74dcf58e
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f9b76a60013
Step 3/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> b2ca6505fed4
Step 4/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 39aae0cbd868
[91mnpm ERR! cb() never called!
[0m[91m
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
```

First time when I got this error, I googled this error, I thought it was because of **ULIMIT** not enough. But It could not fix that error by increasing **ULIMIT**. This my previous [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621767/docker-service-wont-run-inside-container-error-ulimit-error-setting-limit)

So that's why I tried to test docker build in worker nodes. inside EKS worker nodes, im getting the same error. I can build the image in my local machine and normal ec2 instances where docker installed.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002

CMD npm start
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why didnot build image first, then in `POD` just run that container ?

Comment: Inside Jenkins I want to build the image then push into AWS ECR and re-deploy it inside AWS EKS cluster. I'm getting same error inside Jenkins as well, to isolate error I tried to build an image inside the worker node. Then I realized it was not because of jenkins.

Comment: if it is, access to jenkins server and `$su - jenkins` `$sudo npm cache verify` or `$ sudo npm cache clean`

Comment: On my AWS EKS worker nodes your Dockerfile works. Which worker node AMI are you using?

Comment: @weibeld  ami-0b7127e7a2a38802a is this wrong?

Comment: No, it's the right one. What kind of EC2 instance?

Comment: @weibeld EC2 instance type is t2.medium

Comment: It should work. Maybe you can just try on another worker node, or in a fresh EKS cluster.

Comment: I have two nodes, neither works. I will try to add another worker node and test it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm cache verify && npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002

CMD npm start
```

if still not work try clearing `npm cache clean -f` & `npm update` i think it's npm version issue may be.

you can update the npm using `npm i -g npm`

Comment: Step 4/9 : RUN npm cache verify && npm install
 ---> Running in 7f71867735b8
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.013s
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself

Comment: @SarasaGunawardhana have you tried command `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I can build this image without any problem. Can not build the image inside worker nodes inside AWS EKS

Comment: I'm sure, I ran those commands. But it won't work. I dont think this is related to npm. there is something wrong with docker I guess

Comment: is there `package-lock.json` try removing it `Remove package-lock.json`.