# bin/bash: cannot execute binary file on Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm working on a docker container to compile python libraries to ARM architecture.

I'm following the example on this post: https://nmilosev.svbtle.com/compling-arm-stuff-without-an-arm-board-build-pytorch-for-the-raspberry-pi

First I'm creating a Fedora based image with this docker file:

```
FROM fedora

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all \
    && yum -y install nginx && yum clean all \
    && yum -y install git-core \
    && sudo dnf -y  install qemu-system-arm qemu-user-static virt-manager 

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

Then I'm starting the container as:

```
sudo docker run -it mycontainer
```

but the porcess of getting the ARM version of fedora is falling:

```
sudo dnf install --releasever=30 --installroot=/tmp/F30ARM --forcearch=armv7hl --repo=fedora --repo=updates systemd passwd dnf fedora-release vim-minimal openblas-devel blas-devel m4 cmake python3-Cython python3-devel python3-yaml python3-pillow python3-setuptools python3-numpy python3-cffi python3-wheel gcc-c++ tar gcc git make tmux -y
```

The first error I get it just aftter hitting enter:

```
sudo: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted
```

That desapears if I don't use sudo, so I just running:

```
dnf install --releasever=30 --installroot=/tmp/F30ARM --forcearch=armv7hl --repo=fedora --repo=updates systemd passwd dnf fedora-release vim-minimal openblas-devel blas-devel m4 cmake python3-Cython python3-devel python3-yaml python3-pillow python3-setuptools python3-numpy python3-cffi python3-wheel gcc-c++ tar gcc git make tmux -y
```

But some of the libraies fail anyways, the common error among then seems to be this:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/sh’: No such file or directory
```

Also, if I try to start the container as:

```
sudo docker run -it fedora-base /bin/bash
```

I get this other error:

```
/bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: did you check [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/sudo-setrlimit-rlimit-core-operation-not-permitted/4223) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion) ?

Comment: @yohann.martineau Yes, I saw those. But are refered to the setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) error, which is not the main one on this question but the "/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file" I just leave it in case the is some conextion between then that I'm not seen

Comment: I mean i don't understand why you focus on the last error message if you have another error message before? I don't understand why you try to run without root privilege if it doesn't work with.