# Change memlock limit in a Docker container; is it possible?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

I'm running a container from vast.ai, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'd like to change memlock limit in the Docker container. Is it possible?

What I've already tried:

- Changing the memlock limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`; tried:

  - `* - memlock -1`
  - `* - memlock unlimited`
  - `root - memlock unlimited`
- Adding `DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=infinity` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf`;
- Adding `UseLogin yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`;
- Using `ulimit -l unlimited`, "operation not permitted".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For others facing the issue: the problem was that I was trying to change mem lock limit from inside a Docker container.

Apparently, you can only change mem lock limit when spinning up the container:

- `docker run`, use `--ulimit` option — see [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#ulimit) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474407/20330157);
- Docker Compose, see [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ulimits).